# Beginner level SQLite Android App no print result

Tags: java, android-studio, android-sqlite

this app Able to run however it cannot print the data from the database,
i also dont know if the data is able to insert or not.

This is MainActivity.java

```
package com.zikri.sqlitetuto3;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText dataET;
Button addB, delB;
TextView dataTV;
MyDBHandler dbHandler;
String getProduct;
Products products;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startAndroidApp();
}

public void startAndroidApp(){
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this,null,null,1);
    dataET = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dataET);
    addB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addB);
    delB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delB);
    dataTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataTV);

    getProduct = dataET.getText().toString();

    PrintProduct();

    addB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AddProduct(getProduct);
        }
    });

    delB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DelProduct(getProduct);
        }
    });


}

public void PrintProduct(){
    dataTV.setText(dbHandler.PrintProduct());
    dataET.setText("");
}

public void AddProduct(String p){
    products = new Products(p);
    dbHandler.AddProduct(products);
    PrintProduct();
}

public void DelProduct(String p){
    dbHandler.DelProduct(p);
    PrintProduct();
    }
}
```

This is MyDBHandler.java

```
package com.zikri.sqlitetuto3;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
private static final String PRODUCT_TABLE = "product";
private static final String COL_ID = "id";
private static final String COL_PRODUCTNAME = "product_name";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, 
String name,SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    String query = "CREATE TABLE "+PRODUCT_TABLE+" ("+
                    COL_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                    COL_PRODUCTNAME+" TEXT"+");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    String query = "DROP IF EXIST "+PRODUCT_TABLE;
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void AddProduct(Products products){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL_PRODUCTNAME,products.get_productname());
    db.insert(PRODUCT_TABLE,null,values);
    db.close();
}

public void DelProduct(String product){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "DELETE FROM "+PRODUCT_TABLE+
                    "WHERE "+COL_PRODUCTNAME+" = "+product+";";
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.close();
}

public String PrintProduct(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String printproductstring = "";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM "+PRODUCT_TABLE+";";
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(query,null);

    cur.moveToFirst();

    while(cur.moveToNext()){
    printproductstring = 
    printproductstring+cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("product_name"));
    printproductstring = printproductstring + "\n";
    }
    db.close();
    return printproductstring;
    }
}
```

This is Product.java

```
package com.zikri.sqlitetuto3;

public class Products {

private int _ID;
private String _productname;

public Products() {}
public Products(String productname) {
    this._productname = productname;
}

public void set_ID(int _ID) {
    this._ID = _ID;
}
public int get_ID() {
    return _ID;
}

public void set_productname(String _productname) {
    this._productname = _productname;
}

public String get_productname() {
    return _productname;
}

}
```

this is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android=
"http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.zikri.sqlitetuto3.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/dataET" />

<Button
    android:text="INSERT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/dataET"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/addB" />

<Button
    android:text="Delete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addB"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/delB" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/dataTV" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take input when the `button` is `clicked` otherwise `getProduct` will always be empty

```
 addB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getProduct = dataET.getText().toString();
            // ^^^ fetch value when button is clicked
            AddProduct(getProduct);
        }
    });
```

and do the same while deletion

```
delB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getProduct = dataET.getText().toString();
        // ^^^ fetch value when button is clicked
        DelProduct(getProduct);
    }
});
```

Furthermore you can confirm the successful insertion of data by the `return value` of [`insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) which is `long` type and defined as

> the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred

so use it

```
 long id = db.insert(PRODUCT_TABLE,null,values);
 // you can now check the value of id through Logs or Toast 
 db.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

it it very difficult to see database in android is stoered or not you can see eror on logcate if no error means it is stored but not every time .if you want still you have to see in devide manager  its difficult onother solution tack one rooted mobile and intrall root brouser go to android folder inside android folder go to dada inside again go to data and then your package name then database then see there is any file which name related to your database copy this into pc and download sqllite brouser . this long process you can do you will get 100% chance to get database file.if it is created